# Formula for determining number of iterations in a loop, with division increment. Without using counter variable

Tags: algorithm, formula

[Determining Number of Iterations in a loop (Java)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66458376/determining-number-of-iterations-in-a-loop-java)

The formula stated in this question works for for loops where i is being added to or subtracted from. My question is how can this formula be changed to give the number of iterations in a for loop where i is being divided or multiplied by a value.

@WJS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for(int i = M; i < N; i*=k) 
  ...
```

The critical point is when we have been through this loop s times, so that i = M k<sup>s</sup> = N. Take the logarithm of both sides:

```
log(M) + s log(k) = log(N)

s = (log(N)-log(M))/log(k)
```

Use the floor function for `<=` and the ceiling function (minus one) for `<` (which is what WJS did in the linked question). I don't know Java, so I won't attempt to write Java code.

(There might be a problem if you are multiplying an integer counter by a floating-point factor, or something like that, but I will not accept responsibility for such foolishness.)

Comment: Thank you! This makes a lot more sense.

What would it look like for a loop such as 

'for(int i = M; i > N; i /= k)

s = (log(N)-log(M))/log(k)'

For this specific for loop, I'm assuming we have to use the ceiling function on s and subtract the value by one afterwards to acquire the iteration count value correct?

And what base do these logs in the formula use? In computer science log(m) would refer to log base 2 m.

Comment: 1) Just go through the algebra again, starting from `log(M) - s log k = log N`. 2) Yes, that is the way to use `ceiling` for the `>` case. 3) The base *doesn't matter,* you can use 2, or 10, or 7, or e. You must understand the mathematics, or you will have a very hard time getting the code to work.