# Explanation of formula to count # of iterations in a loop

Tags: algorithm, loops, iteration, formula

https://stackoverflow.com/a/66458617/18069660

```
total iterations = (end - start + incr)/incr; // for <=
total iterations = (end - start  + incr - 1)/incr; // for <
```

I have tested both of these formulas and different versions of each for different kinds of for loops. I understand how they work, what I do not understand is how they were made.

Why does the total number of iterations = (the end value minus the start value + the increment)/(divided by the increment).

Why and how were these values chosen and used in such a manner to count the number of iterations. What is the connection between them? How was the formula derived?

Comment: it's pretty basic arithmetic.

Comment: I still don't understand it. I've seen arithmetic formulas for finding a specific term in a sequence, or the sum of n terms. But these formulas are different than those and so I'm trying to learn how they work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's first look at the loop that uses `<=`:

```java
for (int i = start; i <= end; i += incr)
```

Let's look at the value of `i` at each iteration:

| Iteration | value of `i` |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | `start` |
| 2 | `start + incr` |
| 3 | `start + 2*incr` |
| 4 | `start + 3*incr` |
| ... | ... |
| `n` | `start + (n-1)*incr` |

### Case A. `i` becomes equal to `end`

If `end` happens to be one of the values in the second column, for instance, `end == start + k*incr` for some `k`, then we can see the number of iterations is `k+1`.

So we have now the following rule:

If `end` can be written as `start + k*incr` for some integer `k`, then the number of iterations is `k+1` and so we can write:

```
end == start + (numIterations - 1)*incr
```

Which is equivalent to saying:

```
numIterations = (end - start) / incr + 1
```

Or also:

```
numIterations = (end - start + incr) / incr
```

### Case B: `i` never becomes equal to `end`

In this case there is no integer `k` such that `end == start + k*incr`. We *can* find the greatest `k` for which `end < start + k*incr`. In other words, there is a positive `remainder < incr` such that `end == start + k*incr + remainder`.

We repeat the logic in the previous point, but with that non-zero remainder:

```
end == start + (numIterations - 1)*incr + remainder
```

Which is equivalent to saying:

```
numIterations = (end - start - remainder) / incr + 1
```

Or also:

```
numIterations = (end - start - remainder + incr) / incr
```

When `/` represents integer division, we don't have to subtract the `remainder` in that numerator. The integer division will exclude the fractional part that you would get with a real division. So we can simplify to:

```
numIterations = (end - start + incr) / incr
```

I hope this explains the case for a loop with `<= end`.

## Loop with `< end`

When the loop variable cannot become equal to `end`, but at the most to `end-1`, then let's translate this case to a loop where the condition is `<= end - 1`. It is equivalent.

Then apply the formula above by replacing `end` with `end-1`, and we get the second form of the formula you presented.